# Getting undefined value when trying to use with inner functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

Following is my code snippet :

```
function executorFunc(input){
    return input();
}

function mainFunc(){
    var a = 100;

    function innerFunc(){
        var b = 20;
        return a + b;
    }

    executorFunc(innerFunc);
}

var finalVal = mainFunc();

console.log(finalVal);
```

I was in the assumption that `innerFunc` gets created within `mainFunc` and will be aware of outer/enclosing functions data like `a = 100`. To my surprise, it's not. There is something that is doing it wrong or there is something which I have misunderstood in basics of JS.

The final output is `undefined` where I was expecting `120`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expected result as you are not returning the value from `mainFunc` function().

*Use*

```
return executorFunc(innerFunc);
```

```js
function executorFunc(input){
    return input();
}

function mainFunc(){
    var a = 100;

    function innerFunc(){
        var b = 20;
        return a + b;
    }

    return executorFunc(innerFunc);
}

var finalVal = mainFunc();

console.log(finalVal);
```

Comment: I can't accept an answer in less than 10 mins :) Thanks a ton @Satpal !

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `mainFunc` does not return any value. So `finalVal` remains undefined.